# Field `PS_STATUS` not found

Tags: php, битрикс, платежи

Разрабатываю платежный модуль для `Bitrix CMS`. При возвращении покупателя с платежного шлюза пытаюсь обновить статус заказа:

```
$arOrder = CSaleOrder::GetByID($ID);  // $ID - Id заказа в магазинне
CSalePaySystemAction::InitParamArrays($arOrder, $arOrder["ID"]);
// ...
$reponse = $gateway->getOrderStatus($arOrder["ID"]);
$arOrderFields = array(
    "PS_SUM" => $response["amount"]/100,
    "PS_CURRENCY" => $response["currency"],
    "PS_RESPONSE_DATE" => Date(CDatabase::DateFormatToPHP(CLang::GetDateFormat("FULL", LANG))),
    "PS_STATUS" => "Y",
    "PS_STATUS_DESCRIPTION" => $response["cardholderName"],
    "PS_STATUS_MESSAGE" => $response["paymentState"],
    "PS_STATUS_CODE" => "Y"
);
CSaleOrder::Update($arOrder["ID"], $arOrderFields);
```

Но выскакивает следующая ошибка:

```
[Bitrix\Main\ArgumentException] 
Field `PS_STATUS` not found in entity when trying to query Order row. (100)
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bitrix/bitrix/modules/main/lib/entity/datamanager.php:415
...
```

Но если после поиска заказа сделать `var_dump()`, то в нем поле `PS_STATUS`есть:

> array(91) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "8" ["LID"]=> string(2) "s1" ["ACCOUNT_NUMBER"]=> string(1) "8" ["TRACKING_NUMBER"]=> NULL ["PAY_SYSTEM_ID"]=> string(1) "3" ["DELIVERY_ID"]=> string(10) "1451552153" ["DATE_INSERT"]=> string(19) "2016-02-09 12:21:52" ["DATE_UPDATE"]=> string(19) "2016-02-09 12:21:52" ["PERSON_TYPE_ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["USER_ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["PAYED"]=> string(1) "N" ["DATE_PAYED"]=> NULL ["EMP_PAYED_ID"]=> NULL ["DEDUCTED"]=> string(1) "N" ["DATE_DEDUCTED"]=> NULL ["EMP_DEDUCTED_ID"]=> NULL ["REASON_UNDO_DEDUCTED"]=> NULL ["STATUS_ID"]=> string(1) "N" ["DATE_STATUS"]=> string(19) "2016-02-09 12:21:52" ["EMP_STATUS_ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["MARKED"]=> string(1) "N" ["DATE_MARKED"]=> NULL ["EMP_MARKED_ID"]=> NULL ["REASON_MARKED"]=> NULL ["PRICE_DELIVERY"]=> string(8) "500.0000" ["ALLOW_DELIVERY"]=> string(1) "N" ["DATE_ALLOW_DELIVERY"]=> NULL ["EMP_ALLOW_DELIVERY_ID"]=> NULL ["RESERVED"]=> string(1) "N" ["PRICE"]=> string(7) "1579.10" ["CURRENCY"]=> string(3) "RUB" ["DISCOUNT_VALUE"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["TAX_VALUE"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["SUM_PAID"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["USER_DESCRIPTION"]=> NULL ["PAY_VOUCHER_NUM"]=> NULL ["PAY_VOUCHER_DATE"]=> NULL ["ADDITIONAL_INFO"]=> NULL ["COMMENTS"]=> NULL ["CREATED_BY"]=> string(1) "1" ["RESPONSIBLE_ID"]=> NULL ["STAT_GID"]=> NULL ["DATE_PAY_BEFORE"]=> NULL ["DATE_BILL"]=> NULL ["RECURRING_ID"]=> NULL ["LOCKED_BY"]=> NULL ["DATE_LOCK"]=> NULL ["RECOUNT_FLAG"]=> string(1) "Y" ["AFFILIATE_ID"]=> NULL ["DELIVERY_DOC_NUM"]=> NULL ["DELIVERY_DOC_DATE"]=> NULL ["UPDATED_1C"]=> string(1) "N" ["ORDER_TOPIC"]=> NULL ["XML_ID"]=> NULL ["ID_1C"]=> NULL ["VERSION_1C"]=> NULL ["VERSION"]=> string(1) "0" ["EXTERNAL_ORDER"]=> string(1) "N" ["STORE_ID"]=> NULL ["CANCELED"]=> string(1) "N" ["EMP_CANCELED_ID"]=> NULL ["DATE_CANCELED"]=> NULL ["REASON_CANCELED"]=> NULL ["BX_USER_ID"]=> NULL ["DATE_INSERT_FORMAT"]=> string(19) "09.02.2016 12:21:52" ["DATE_UPDATE_SHORT"]=> string(19) "2016-02-09 00:00:00" ["DATE_STATUS_SHORT"]=> string(19) "2016-02-09 00:00:00" ["DATE_CANCELED_SHORT"]=> NULL ["BY_RECOMMENDATION"]=> string(1) "N" ["LOCK_STATUS"]=> string(5) "green" ["LOCK_USER_NAME"]=> NULL ["RESPONSIBLE_LOGIN"]=> NULL ["RESPONSIBLE_NAME"]=> NULL ["RESPONSIBLE_LAST_NAME"]=> NULL ["RESPONSIBLE_SECOND_NAME"]=> NULL ["RESPONSIBLE_EMAIL"]=> NULL ["RESPONSIBLE_WORK_POSITION"]=> NULL ["RESPONSIBLE_PERSONAL_PHOTO"]=> NULL ["PS_STATUS"]=> NULL ["PS_STATUS_CODE"]=> NULL ["PS_STATUS_DESCRIPTION"]=> NULL ["PS_STATUS_MESSAGE"]=> NULL ["PS_SUM"]=> NULL ["PS_CURRENCY"]=> NULL ["PS_RESPONSE_DATE"]=> NULL ["USER_LOGIN"]=> string(5) "admin" ["USER_NAME"]=> string(5) "Админ" ["USER_LAST_NAME"]=> string(7) "Админов" ["USER_EMAIL"]=> string(14) "admin@admin.ru" ["DATE_UPDATE_FORMAT"]=> string(19) "09.02.2016 12:21:52" ["DATE_STATUS_FORMAT"]=> string(19) "09.02.2016 12:21:52" }

Причем, если удалить из массива `PS_STATUS`, то `Bitrix CMS` будет ругаться на другие поля: `PS_STATUS_CODE`, `PS_STATUS_DESCRIPTION` и так далее. Хотя в [официальной документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/sale/classes/csaleorder/csaleorder__update.a8be5ffa.php) эти поля описаны.

Comment: Может A или Т русские в слове STATUS?

Comment: @Naumov, точно нет :)

Comment: var_dump($arOrder) что кажет

Comment: @Naumov, обновил вопрос

Comment: А что мешает для обновления статуса заказа использовать соответствующий метод [`CSaleOrder::StatusOrder`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/sale/classes/csaleorder/csaleorder__statusorder.f21c0322.php)

Comment: @НиколайСарры, кроме статуса заказа есть еще ответ от платежной системы, описание и сообщение. И насколько я знаю, для них отдельного метода нет.

Comment: Очень странно...

Comment: Как вариант лушче написать им в поддержку, а еще лучше на форуме задать вопрос.

Comment: @НиколайСарры, [уже](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/forums/messages/forum6/topic79589/message407559/?result=new#message407559)